# Linux: Compiling userspace code for handling driver's ioctl

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, cross-compiling, embedded-linux

I'm new to kernel compilation and am trying to cross-compile a userspace program for an existing kernel driver for an ARM board. Basically, I'm trying to access the ioctl facilities of the driver.

I'm using arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (4.9.2).

I can compile the kernel successfully. The userspace code looks like following

**getefuse.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h> 
#include <linux/amlogic/efuse.h> //The driver's header file
....
```

When I try to compile the userspace code, I get entangled in a mesh of 'include' file issues. The kernel source code resides at `/home/cheema/boards/linux/`

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I/home/cheema/boards/linux/include getefuse.c
In file included from getefuse.c:7:0:
/home/cheema/boards/linux/include/linux/amlogic/efuse.h:5:24: fatal   error: mach/efuse.h: No such file or directory
#include <mach/efuse.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

I try to add the missing 'include' file path. But every time I add another file path, the compiler gives the `No such file or directory` error for a different file.

I believe I have to use kernel's config files(Makefile??) to get out of this mess, but don't know how.

Comment: You need to add another -I option to tell the compiler where mach/efuse.h lives. You can try to include the kernel makefile in yours, and use the flags as defined there, but add yours to them.

Comment: @ventsyv - I already mentioned, its an every increasing mess. For every new `-I` that I add,  the error shifts somewhere else. For ex:
`$ arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I/home/cheema/boards/linux/include -I../../../arch/arm/mach-meson8/include getefuse.c
....
....
from /home/cheema/boards/linux/include/linux/amlogic/efuse.h:75,
from getefuse.c:7:
/home/cheema/boards/linux/include/linux/atomic.h:4:24: fatal error: asm/atomic.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/atomic.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.`

Comment: And then there is the problem of too many different directories where `mach/efuse.h` exists. So only the kernel config can identify and pick the correct `mach/efuse.h`.

Comment: Can you post the makefile for the kernel?

Comment: is `amlogic` your board ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the file `efuse.h` includes `mach/efuse.h`. But `mach` is only defined under Kernel build system. It does not mean anything to cross-compiler at user-space.

You need to include only the file that has the ioclt number. If it is `mach/efuse.h`, then include only that file as `#include <path_to_file>`

You should be able to identify your `mach`, it depends on your board.

Comment: Yea, it worked. I had to copy the relevant defines from efuse.h to another file and include that file. Thanks.